pgfplot on closed interval doesn't reach endpoints
I'm editing a textbook that has many images (around 700) written using pgfplot.
When the function being graphed has a square root, (or in general if the domain is a closed interval) I am running into domain issues.
Here is an example: the function f(x)=x^2\sqrt{4-x^2} has domain [-2, 2]. I want the plot to include the x-intercepts at (-2,0) and (2,0). But the endpoints of the graph are plotted just off the x-axis.
I've tried increasing the number of sample points, or using sample at, but the result is the same. How can I push the graph a bit further, so that it reaches the axis? I chose an example with integer endpoints, but the problem is even worse if the endpoints are irrational.
Code:
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line = middle,
    axis y line = middle,
    xlabel = {$x$},
    ylabel = {$y$},
    ymin=-.9,ymax=3.5,%
    xmin=-3.5,xmax=3.5,%
]

\addplot [blue,thick,{Circle}-{Circle},domain=-2:2,samples=100] {x^2*sqrt(4-x^2)};


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}

Result:


Hmmm... Can't check now, but what happens if you remove the arrows?

That helps! If I replace {Circle}-{Circle} with - and add the endpoints separately with a \draw command, there's no visible gap.

Would just samples=101 work? I am unsure which number of samples would be best here though ... But you want the two circles to be placed centered on the x axis, right? Then, drawing them separately is probably the way to go.

The extra sample point improves the left endpoint. But I guess the problem is that the dots provided by the arrows library have their edge at the desired point, rather than the centre.

Yes, you could adjust this using shorten <=-2.4pt, shorten >=-2.4pt. The radius of the circle is per default three times the width of the line it is attached to, as you set the line width to thick which means 0.8pt, this results in 2.4pt.

Ah, yes -- that works better than my idea.

It is probably a better idea to place the circles separately or as marks, but you could do the following:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    ymin=-.9, ymax=3.5,
    xmin=-3.5, xmax=3.5,
]

\addplot[
    blue, thick, {Circle}-{Circle},
    domain=-2:2, samples=101,
    shorten <=-2.4pt,
    shorten >=-2.4pt
] {x^2*sqrt(4-x^2)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

First, using samples=101 we can adjust the end point of the plot so that it sits on the x axis. Then, using shorten <=-2.4pt, shorten >=-2.4pt, we shift the arrow tips outwards. Per default, the radius of the circle arrow tip is three times the width of the width of the line it is attached to. You set the line to be thick which is 0.8pt. Thus, we need to shift 2.4pt.


Or just add marks:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    ymin=-.9, ymax=3.5,
    xmin=-3.5, xmax=3.5,
]

\addplot[
    blue, thick, 
    domain=-2:2, samples=101
] {x^2*sqrt(4-x^2)};

\addplot[
    mark=*,
    blue,
    draw=none,
] coordinates { (-2,0) (2,0) };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Using the suggestion from Rmano in the comments, I have a solution that works:
Replace
\addplot [blue,thick,{Circle}-{Circle},domain=-2:2,samples=100] {x^2*sqrt(4-x^2)};

with
\addplot [blue,thick,-,domain=-2:2,samples=100] {x^2*sqrt(4-x^2)};
\draw [blue,fill=blue]  (axis cs: 2,0) circle (2pt);
\draw [blue,fill=blue]  (axis cs: -2,0) circle (2pt);

and the gaps disappear.
The two \draw commands add the dots at the endpoints that I was trying to get from the arrows library.
